# Trouble in populating the Links under a Main Link ,Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the webpage http://www.quikr.com,
In the main page, they have listed the categories Mobile phones,Electronics & Technology etc.

I want to click one of the links like Electronics & Technology and get all the links inside a List.

I'm not able to populate my arraylist because the locators i'm trying with are throwing errors

I tried giving

`List<WebElement>link_boxes=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='divExpand18222212654']"));`

`List<WebElement> link_boxes=driver.findElements(By.id("divExpand18222212654"))`

Its not working ,Please provide me a solution for this.

Comment: Care to let us in on the secret of exactly *what* errors you face or is it too secret you cannot tell us?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve the links under the `div` element with id `divExpand18222212654` with the following CSS expression:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#divExpand18222212654 a"));
```

Comment: LaurentG,Thanks,the problem is i'm not able to get the text of the hyperlinks,its giving me as Firefox Driver.My code to retrieve links is -for(int j=0;j<link_boxes.size();j++){                             WebElement box = link_boxes.get(j);
List<WebElement> links = box.findElements(By.tagName("a"));    for(int i=1 ; i<links.size();i++){
System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
 }
}

Comment: @user2549379: If you've got extra information, then it's worth editing your original question to include it there; that will make it easier for people reading it to understand it all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
public void showSubLinksListByName(String name) {
    String linkSelectorTemplate = ""//span[.='%s']";
    String subListSelectorTemplate = "div#%s";

    WebElement link = driver.findElement(
            By.xpath(String.format(linkSelectorTemplate, name)));
    String id = link.getAttribute('id').replace("chpCategoryExpand", "");

    By subCategoriesLinksSelector = By.css(
              String.format(subListSelectorTemplate, id));

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
         ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(subCategoriesLinksSelector);
}
```

After that sub list is visible and you can do whatever you want with it.